# Using COUNTIFS on 3 different columns and then need to SUM a 4th column?

Tags: excel-2010

I have written this formula below.  I do not know the correct part of this formula that will add the numbers I have in Column AB2:AB552.  As it is, this formula is counting the number of cells in that range that has numbers in it, but I need it to total those numbers as my final result.  Any help would be great.

```
=COUNTIFS(Cases!B2:B552,"1",Cases!G2:G552,"c*",Cases!X2:X552,"No",**Cases!AB2:AB552,">0"**)
```

Comment: SUMIFS? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx

Comment: How do I combine the COUNTIFS function for the first 3 criteria and then add the SUMIFS function to add the numbers in AB:AB552

Comment: I changed the COUNTIFS to SUMIFS and it did not add the numbers in AB2:AB552 as my final result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't actually need the intermediate counts, the sumifs function should give you the final result:

```
=SUMIFS(Cases!AB2:AB552,Cases!B2:B552,1,Cases!G2:G552,"c",Cases!X2:X552,"No",Cases!AB2:AB552,">0")
```

Testing this with some limited data:

```
Row B G X   AB 
 2  2 a No  10 
 3  1 c No  24 
 4  2 c No   4 
 5  1 c No   0 
 6  1 a Yes  9 
 7  2 c No  12 
 8  2 c No   6 
 9  2 b No   0 
10  1 b No   0 
11  1 a No  10 
12  2 c No   6 
13  1 c No  20 
14  1 c No   4 
15  1 b Yes 22 
16  1 b Yes 22
```

the formula above returned 48, the sum of AB3, AB13, and AB14, which were the only rows matching all 4 criteria

Comment: PERFECT !!!!!! Thank you very very much.  You solved this in minutes after I spent 3-4 hours trying to figure it out.  Again, thanks.